# Angular 2 Dart Template syntax: How to access static methods?

Tags: templates, dart, angular-dart, angular2-dart, dart-angular-templates

Is there a way to access static methods from a template in Dart?

Problem is as follows:

*offer.dart:*

```
class Offer {
  static String getPriceString(double price) {
    return euroFormat.format(price) + " €";
  }
}
```

**First Try:**

*main_component.html:*

```
<div class="offer" *ngFor="let offer of offers">
 <span class="offer_price">{{ offer.getPriceString(1.9) }}</span>
</div>
```

*Exception:*

> EXCEPTION: NoSuchMethodError: Class 'Offer' has no instance method
>   'getPriceString'. Receiver: Instance of 'Offer' Tried calling:
>   getPriceString(4.9)

**Second Try:**

*main_component.html:*

```
<div class="offer" *ngFor="let offer of offers">
 <span class="offer_price">{{ Offer.getPriceString(1.9) }}</span>
</div>
```

*Exception 2:*

> EXCEPTION: NoSuchMethodError: Class 'MainComponent' has no instance
>   getter 'Offer'. Receiver: Instance of 'MainComponent' Tried calling:
>   Offer

If I remove the `static` keyword from `getPriceString()` everything works like called in "First Try" but it feels not nice because I lose the possibility for static call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The scope for binding expressions is the components class instance.

If you want to access something from outside that scope you need to provide a means to access it through the components class instance (like a getter)

```
class MyComponent {
  String get someStaticProp => SomeClass.someStaticProp;
}
```

then you can access it in view bindings like

```
<div>{{someStaticProp}}</div>
```

Comment: So there is now way to access it except if I extend the class with a possibility to access the property/method in a non-static manner?

Comment: Exactly. It's the same in TypeScript. I saw it mentioned that they consider  allowing access to statics in TypeScript eventually. I can imagine that they'll add it to Dart as well when TypeScript supports it.